# jQuery + thymeleaf

Tags: java, jquery, spring, thymeleaf

I have problem with get data from switch in thymeleaf.

I do it in this way, for normal data without switch it works:

```
<tr>
    <td>Zatrudniony</td>
    <td th:attr="id='datewo' + ${employee.empEvidenceNumber}">
        <span th:text="${employee.empFirstWorkDay}"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and my jQuery to show data from this row I can display in my modal input field:

```
var empDepartmentId = $('#dep' + empEvidenceNumber).text();
$("#empDepartmentId").val(empDepartmentId);
```

but this jQuery code doesn't display data from thymeleaf switch:

```
<tr>
    <td>Jest kierownikiem</td>
    <td th:attr="id='isman' + ${employee.empEvidenceNumber}">
        <div th:switch="${employee.empIsManager}">
            <span th:case="1" th:text="tak"></span>
            <span th:case="*" th:text="nie"></span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I tried to set this id attribute in div and for span components but still nothing. 
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
    <td>Jest kierownikiem</td>
    <td th:attr="id='isman' + ${employee.empEvidenceNumber}">
        <th:block th:switch="${employee.empIsManager}">
            <div th:case="1">
                <span th:text="tak"></span> 
            </div>
            <div th:case="*">
                <span th:case="*" th:text="nie"></span>
            </div>
        </th:block>
    </td>
</tr>
```